# Bug, when using rehype-react for rendering htmlAST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using gatsby for rendering pages from markdown and I need my react components declared in .md files rendered as well as static content. So, I'm using `gatsby-transformer-remark`, `gatsby-remark-component` and `remark-generic-extensions` (for rendering html tags with custom classes and attributes) plugins. The syntax in markdown for react component is valid (`<another-page></another-page>`) and my component renders as it should. But there is a bug that occurs when I interact with radio inputs that are rendered as static html. So, when I click any radio from group, every time this group resets, and I should click on it twice to make it work. When I remove the 'click' listener in dev tools, attached to `document` by `react-dom` library (used by rehype as well), the bug disappears. I suppose, that rehype-react adds this listener, because previously, I have rendered static html without react components (and without rehype-react), using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and radio inputs worked ok. Here is the video, describing my issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LAKSzApCcE

```
import RehypeReact from 'rehype-react'
import AnotherPage from './another-page'

const renderAst = new RehypeReact({
  createElement: React.createElement,
  components: {
    "another-page": AnotherPage
  }
}).Compiler

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark } = data
  const { frontmatter, htmlAst } = markdownRemark
  return renderAst(htmlAst)
};
```

Comment: Hm,probably remark was invoked twice? Gatsby config pls